# AutoLayout can’t display correctly in iOS10 with Xcode8

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode8, ios10

I use autolayout in a project of mine.All the constraints are blue and it can display correctly in configuration bar.But when I run my project on Simulator the constraints are wrong and it can't display correctly.I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.I really want to know how to solve the problem.It makes me very annoyed.I hope someone can help me.

Thank you very much!

**(Picture2 is what displays in simulator.The last picture is the constraints.)**

[image: Picture2]

[image: This is my constraints]

Comment: show your constraints in storybord

Comment: I have added the constraints picture.

Comment: Right constraint is equal or greater than?

Comment: I have solved the problem by myself yesterday.I found the button I set constraints was an accessory Type Button.I have customized an accessory Type Button by myself.The accessory Type Button has a fixed position.If you set constraints for it,it will be puzzled.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

- remove all current constrains from this view controller by clicking on issue icon -> clear constrains (in the second section)
- drag the items to the place you want on the view.
- select an item
- open align -> set horizontally in container (current canvas value ) by clicking on the black arrow beside number 0
  [align menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSMvJ.jpg)
  Then set vertically in container (current canvas value)
- open Pin icon -> set value to width and set value to height 
  [pin menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoBaJ.png)
- in the same pin menu check aspect ratio (in the second section )